# Mouting NTFS drive, no write access

Tags: mount, raspbian, ntfs

Copying scripts from the previous isntall of Debian for Raspberry.

The commant should mount an external NTFS drive to a folder. Before the new install, this command worked:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 -o umask=007,gid=wheel,gid=www-data,rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,allow_other ~/Ext-hdd/
```

Now, I get the

```
ntfs: (device sdb1): parse_options(): Unrecognized mount option allow_other.
```

I tried removing this option, but without it I don't have write access to the drive, which is something that I need. I tried tweeking the flags

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 -o umask=007,gid=wheel,uid=1001,rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime ~/Ext-hdd/
```

But I still cannot get write access.

Comment: "allow_other":     This option overrides the security measure restricting file access to the user mounting the filesystem. **This option is only allowed to root, but this restriction can be overridden by the 'user_allow_other' option in the /etc/fuse.conf file. **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
sudo apt install ntfsprogs
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: installation of ntfs-3g fixed the `non existing allow_other option` problem.

Answer (score 3):

Linux Kernel NTFS driver only supports read-only mounts. For read-write access you need install and use [`ntfs-3g`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ntfs-3g/ntfs-3g.8.en.html) FUSE driver. To explicitly use ntfs-3g instead of the Kernel driver, specify it in mount type option:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g ...
```